# Flutter Rest API Trying to get property 'password' of non-obj

Tags: api, flutter, rest

Am trying to create a login form using Rest API in flutter however I keep getting errors.
For login, the API requires 3 vaiables; email, password and device

Here is my login function

```
String email;
  String password;
  
  String device="mobile";
  

  TextEditingController passwordcontroller=TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailcontroller=TextEditingController();

loginfunction(String email, String password, String device)async{

    // Map data={"email":email,
    // "password":password,"device":device};

    var jsonData;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var response= await http.post('https://f.nz/api/auth/Login',headers:{
      "key": "Client-Version",
      "value": "{{client_version}}-1",
      "type": "text"
    },

    body: {
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
      "device": device,
    });
   // return response.data;

    if (response.statusCode==200){
      jsonData= json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonData["token"]);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    OtpPage()));
      });
    }
    else{
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);

      print(email);
      print(device);
    }

  }
```

And here is where am calling the function after filling in the email and password fields

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                try{
                  

                  await loginfunction(email, password,device);


                }
                catch(e){
                  setState(() {
                    error=e.message;
                  });

                }

              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                height: 35.0,
                width: 150.0,
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                  color: Color(0xffa6ce38),
                  elevation: 7.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Sign in",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

everytime I run the code and try signing in this is the error in the terminal

D/libc-netbsd( 7365): [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=fhm.soop.co.nz; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
D/libc-netbsd( 7365): getaddrinfo( app_uid:10366
D/libc-netbsd( 7365): getaddrinfo() uid prop:
D/libc-netbsd( 7365): getaddrinfo() getuid():10366
D/libc-netbsd( 7365): [getaddrinfo]: mtk ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
D/libc-netbsd( 7365): getaddrinfo: fhm.soop.co.nz get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365): 
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365): A PHP Error was encountered
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):

Severity: Notice

I/flutter ( 7365):

Message:  Trying to get property 'email' of non-object

I/flutter ( 7365):

Filename: auth/Login.php

I/flutter ( 7365):

Line Number: 43

I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):

Backtrace:

I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):          
I/flutter ( 7365):          File: C:\xampp\htdocs\api\application\controllers\auth\Login.php
I/flutter ( 7365):          Line: 43
I/flutter ( 7365):          Function: _error_handler

I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):          
I/flutter ( 7365):          File: C:\xampp\htdocs\api\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php
I/flutter ( 7365):          Line: 708
I/flutter ( 7365):          Function: index_post            
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):          
I/flutter ( 7365):          File: C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php
I/flutter ( 7365):          Line: 308
I/flutter ( 7365):          Function: require_once          
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365): 
I/flutter ( 7365): 
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365): A PHP Error was encountered
I/flutter ( 7365):
I/flutter ( 7365):

Severity: Notice

I/flutter ( 7365):

Message:  Trying to get property 'password' of non-obj
I/flutter ( 7365): 400
I/flutter ( 7365): email@email.com
I/flutter ( 7365): mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an email that doesn't exist in your database, this is the result from your php server. I see that your error says `email@email.com`. Your server is looking for the user, but doesn't find it, and returns null. Or you could be parsing the data incorrectly server-side. I would start checking there first.

Your error also says

```
Message: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object

I/flutter ( 7365):
Filename: auth/Login.php
message:  A PHP Error was encountered
```

So, it's almost clear it's not a flutter issue, just be sure that you are indeed passing in your name and password from TextEditingControllers to your POST request.

To validate this theory also, hardcode your credentials in the request and see if the error persists and doesn't change, then definitely go to your php code.

```
body: {
      "email": 'email@gmail.com',
      "password": 'youSuperStrongpassword124234',
      "device": device,
    });
```

Also, you should `jsonEncode` your POST request's body.

Comment: I've tried hardcoding the values but am still getting the error. However when I try to run the same thing on postman it works fine

Comment: try jsonEncoding your body

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working after encoding

Comment: You're most welcome, kindly consider marking it as an answer to your question.